# Two separate ASyncTasks wrongly combining data when processing JSON

Tags: android, json, concurrency, android-asynctask

I have a project with a TabLayout + ViewPager to scroll through two different fragments (one shows data happening currently and the other shows all data).

In the onCreateView's of both of these I call the same ASyncTask class with the only difference being the params changing.

```
FetchItems asyncTask = new FetchItems(getContext(), this);
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"someParams");
```

The JSON result is then processed here:

```
try {
        LinkedList<LeagueItem> leagues = new LinkedList<>();
        LeagueItem newLeague;
        //For every league in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonBody.length(); i++) {
            newLeague = new LeagueItem();
            //Hold the league games
            JSONObject jsonLeagueInfo = jsonBody.getJSONObject(i);

            newLeague.setLeagueName(jsonLeagueInfo.getString("name"));

            JSONArray leagueMatches = jsonLeagueInfo.getJSONArray("matches");

            //For every match in that league
            for(int j = 0;j<leagueMatches.length();j++){
                JSONObject matchInformation = leagueMatches.getJSONObject(j);
                JSONArray teamsArray = matchInformation.getJSONArray("teams");
                MatchItem currentMatch = new MatchItem();

                //For both teams in the match
                for(int k=0;k<2;k++){
                    JSONObject teamInfo = teamsArray.getJSONObject(k);

                    String name = teamInfo.getString("name");
                    String logoUrl = teamInfo.getString("logo");

                    JSONObject scores = teamInfo.getJSONObject("results");
                    String runningScore =  scores.getString("runningscore");

                    TeamItem currentTeam = new TeamItem(shortName, logoUrl, Integer.parseInt(runningScore), homeNum);
                    currentMatch.addTeam(currentTeam);

                }
                newLeague.addMatch(currentMatch);

            }
            leagues.add(newLeague);
        }
        return leagues;
}
```

I'm finding that both objects returned have crossover data which shouldn't be there. Both of the parent objects are correct in that they add the correct number of league items, however every league contains pretty much all the data that I'm iterating over. Am I missing something huge here? I thought that by calling executeOnExecuter I would be getting two completely separate threads with different objects.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON that you see? You may [edit] your question

Comment: Yea no problem, added an example API return result.

Comment: I'm very sorry, i was able to fix this myself due to an unrelated problem of keeping a static reference to a variable. Thanks very much for having a look @cricket_007 !

Comment: I figured that was the problem, but I wasnt too sure. Glad you figured it out